# Why the unnamed parameter warning discrepency between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following C/C++ program, and I compile it with all warnings on.

`int foo(int x) { return 5; }`

The C++ compiler gives me a warning about unreferenced formal parameter. When I remove "x" so that the signature reads "int foo(int)", the compiler is happy.

The C compiler, on the other hand, likes the named parameter and issues warning when it is unnamed.

**EDIT**: It issues an error, not warning.

Why the difference? What's the rationale?

P.S. I'm using the GNU compiler toolchain.

Comment: Are you sure the C compiler just issues a warning when you leave out the name? It should be an error. The C standard does not allow leaving out the parameter name.

Comment: What's the difference? The language.

Comment: @sepp2k - the C and C++ standards do not distinguish between warnings and errors. A violation of a diagnosable rule requires "a diagnostic". Having issued a diagnostic, a conforming compiler is free to continue compiling the code and to do something reasonable with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason for C might be that it still has the old-style parameter list that only consist of identifiers:

```
int f(to)
double to; {
  return to;
}
```

So basically when it only sees an identifier, it has to assume that this is a variable name and not a type.

Comment: This explains why C requires it.
But why wouldn't C++? I mean, what's the value of omitting them? Or forcing people to do special handling? Does the compiler have some sort of optimization it can perform in such cases?

Comment: @Filip: C++ never had this style of optionally-typed parameter; parameters have always had mandatory types and optional names, because types have always been a fundamental aspect of C++. C dates back to a time when the value of types hadn't been fully appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

They are different languages, with different rules.

In C, function parameters must have names; I'm surprised that you get a warning rather than an error. I guess the rationale is that there's no good reason for an unused parameter; if you don't need it, then why should it exist?  (Of course, there are valid cases for ignoring parameters, such as when using function pointers that specify a particular set of arguments; presumably, the powers that be didn't consider that common enough to be worth relaxing the rules for. If you need to ignore it, then `(void)unused;` should suppress any "unused parameter" warnings you might otherwise get.)

In C++, functions must often have a particular signature, in order to override a virtual function declared in a base class, or to match a particular usage of a template parameter. It's quite possible that not all the parameters of that signature are required for all overrides, in which case it's quite reasonable to ignore that parameter. I'm guessing that that's the rationale for allowing you to leave it unnamed.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about why C requires parameter names - there are certainly cases where it makes sense to have unused arguments in C: for example callback functions need to have a specified signature, but might not need all their arguments. I'd imagine it's rather because otherwise there'd be ambiguity with the old-style syntax in which parameter *types* were optional. Or maybe just to keep the language definition simple.

Comment: In C you may need to provide a function as a function pointer parameter to some other function.  The required signature of the function may have parameters that you don't use, but you need to define them anyway.  So it is the same situation as virtual functions and so on in C++.

Comment: @sepp2k: As I said, it's just a guess; I wasn't involved with any of the many decisions that guided C's evolution over the last five decades. And I was just adding a note about valid use cases as you wrote your comment.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are different languages with different rules, and this is one of many areas where they don't behave very much like the other.

[C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.9.1 Function deﬁnitions
>
> ...
> 5 If the declarator includes a parameter type list, **the declaration of each parameter shall
> include an identiﬁer**, except for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single
> parameter of type `void`, in which case there shall not be an identiﬁer. No declaration list
> shall follow.

Emphasis mine.

[C++ 2011 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)

> #### 8.4 Function deﬁnitions [dcl.fct.def]
>
> #### 8.4.1 In general [dcl.fct.def.general]
>
> ...
> 6
> [ Note: Unused parameters need not be named. For example,
>
> ```
> void print(int a, int) {
> std::printf("a = %d\n",a);
> }
> ```
>
> — end note ]

Now, as to the larger philosophical question of *why* C requires an identifier for all parameters whether they're used or not and C++ does not, remember the following:

1. C predates C++ by a decade or so;
2. C was designed so that compilers for it are easy to write;
3. C doesn't support function overloading

In short, there's no good reason why C should allow unused parameters to be unnamed, and at least one good reason (simplify parsing) why it *shouldn't*.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree about it simplifying the parser.  The compiler still needs to be able to parse function pointer declarations, and those don't require parameter names.  And once your parser can handle those, it doesn't seem like it should be much additional work to handle function declarations and definitions in general.

Answer (score 0):

I've always wondered about that too, but in any case, you can make it work in both it by actually naming the argument `x`, and somewhere in the body saying:

```
(void)x;
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but I upvoted it. I do this in my own code. It's a good way, if annoying, if keeping the warning to be generated in cases where it actually helps ("oops, I'm using the wrong parameter!").

Comment: @JimBuck - unless you've got a helpful compiler that warns you about code that has no effect, despite the cast. Not that I've seen that happen. It's just that I've never liked this solution (but I didn't down vote it).

Comment: @PeteBecker - The point of the cast is to prevent such a "code has no effect" warning from happening. This has worked on all compilers that I deal with (gcc, LLVM, VC++, and SNC [PlayStation]).

Comment: @JimBuck - yes, I understood that. I considered adding a smiley, and perhaps should have.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can fix the warning in C++ by removing the parameter names. In C it is not allowed to leave out parameter names. So if your C compiler produced the same warning, there would be no way for you to remove it. So your C compiler does not produce such a warning.