# Only report C warnings in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-warnings

I'm current working in a C project with visual studio (community 2015). I'm attempted to remove warnings from my project. Currently I'm getting the following warning:

> C4100: 'argc': unreferenced formal parameter

Searching on why I get this warning I found this stack overflow question:
[Why the unnamed parameter warning discrepency between C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12181852/1248889)

From what I understand, this is a C++ warning, not a C warning, even though my file ends with a `.c` extension. Is there any setting in visual studio that restricts building warnings to just C?

Comment: It's not an "error", it's a [warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26kb9fy0.aspx). You get it because you raised your warning level from default level 3 to level 4, which causes the compiler to emit more warnings. It's supposed to be a remainder that you have some arguments that you don't use, but it can safely be ignored.

Comment: You're right. I knew it was a warning, so I'm not sure why I incorrectly titled it "error." I've edited the original question to match.

Comment: To eliminate: `(void)argc;`

Comment: ... or `int main(void)`

Comment: Visual Studio is first and foremost a C++ compiler. I don't think there's a way to configure it to show only C warnings. Honestly, although I love Windows and Visual Studio, C compliance is not one of their strengths (unless you're coding in straight ansi-c). I always use gcc as my main C compiler.

Comment: If you know `C4100` is a c++ warning, you can use `#pragma warning(push) 
#pragma warning(disable:C4100)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a C warning.

It is saying that you have a parameter to a function that is not actually used within the function.

Note: if the function is `main()`, then never assume anything about the parameters, especially the number of command line parameters.

This means do not reference anything beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure that parameter actually exists.